# Filling holes in objects that touch the border of an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy, image-segmentation

I'm trying to fill holes in the below image.

[image: image to be filled]

When I use SciPy's binary_fill_holes(), I am generally successful, with the exception of objects that touch the image's border.

[image]

Are there any existing Python functions that can fill holes in objects that touch the border? I tried adding a white border around the image, but that just resulted in the entire image being filled.

Comment: What if you draw a white border, but leave a hole in it next to a black region?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This assumes that there is more background than other stuff. It basically does a connected component analysis on the image. Extract the largest component (assumed to be the background), and sets everything else to white.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage.morphology, skimage.data

img = skimage.data.imread('j1ESv.png', 1)
labels = skimage.morphology.label(img)
labelCount = np.bincount(labels.ravel())
background = np.argmax(labelCount)
img[labels != background] = 255
plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

[image]