# Fill the elements close to the region of the image

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I have black and white image, which has some white elements touching the border of the image[image].

I am trying to fill in these white parts (on this image there is only one part, but there can be multiple) with a black color. My only idea is to iterate over the pixels on the border of the image and whenever I see a white pixel run the algorithm which recursively fills all the white pixels of the surrounding white pixels.

Although this will clearly produce the result I want, I hope that there is an easier way to achieve this with numpy/scipy/scikit-image.

While searching through the SO, the only related question I have found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310489/filling-holes-in-objects-that-touch-the-border-of-an-image). The question sounds similar to what I want, but actually solves another problem. Is there any hope to find an easy solution for me?

Comment: The concept of `contours` can solve your problem pretty easily, can you use opencv ? because I am not sure if scipy or numpy have an API for finding contours in a given image.

Comment: @ZdaR I am free to use anything I want. The thing is that I am not that familiar with OpenCV. But if you can provide a nice explanation, I would be really thankful.

Comment: Your input image also has a white border around it ? Because in that case, first you need to crop image removing that border as well?

Comment: @ZdaR yes, sometimes I have it (not always and not from all the sides). If I were to use my recursive approach it wold not make any difference, but I guess in your case it does.

Comment: Do you have the information about the border width on each side ?

Comment: @ZdaR no, they can be of various size starting from 0% to 20%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

Sorry for my misunderstanding. I think you are looking for the module clear_border.

Clear_border(image) fills all white areas attached to the border with black (or other values).

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io

from skimage.segmentation import clear_border

image = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])


clear_border(image)

io.imshow(image)
io.show()
```

For further info please have a look at:
http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.11.x/api/skimage.segmentation.html#clear-border

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, I have added info on the module clear_border whcih you are probably looking for.

Comment: Yes, yes and one more time yes. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the second chance ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Give [scipy.ndimage.label](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) a shot.

Here's a sketch (untested):

```
labeled_image, _ = scipy.ndimage.label(binarized_image)
for region in np.union1d(labeled_image[[0,-1]].flatten(),
                         labeled_image[:,[0,-1]].flatten()):
    binarized_image[labeled_image == region] = 0
```

The above code segments the image into connected regions of the same colour. Each one is assigned an integer value in some order. `labeled_image[[0, -1]]` and `labeled_image[:, [0, -1]]` are the top and bottom rows, and left and right columns of the image respectively. `array.flatten()` is used to get them into a shape usable by union1d, which in this context will return all the region labels in contact with the boundary. We iterate over these, and colour all these regions black in the binarized image.

Comment: I obtained my original image with `label`. How will this help me to get which of the labeled regions is connected to a border?

Comment: There were some syntax errors in my original answer. `label` should not give you your original image unless the image is only two regions, instead it should be a different integer in every connected region. `uinion1d` and its arguments gives you an array containing the labels of regions connected to the border.